# JNI method to return bitmap from file path

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

Below is my code to get byte[] from the specified by in parameters but i want to get the bitmap that the path represent not just the byte array so that i don't have to convert it to bitmap in java.

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray  JNICALL Java_com_lightbox_android_photoprocessing_PhotoProcessing_getFile(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj,jstring string)
{
    char * path;

    path = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars( env, string , NULL ) ;
    char* buffer = 0;
    long length;
    FILE * f = fopen (path,"r"); //was "rb"

    if (f)
    {
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell (f);
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        buffer = (char*)malloc ((length+1)*sizeof(char));
        if (buffer)
        {
            fread (buffer, sizeof(char), length, f);
        }
        fclose (f);
    }
    buffer[length+1] = '\0';


    int size = length+1;
    jbyteArray array = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, size);
    (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, array, 0, size,buffer);
    free(buffer);
    return array;
}
```

Comment: A *Bitmap* instance is Java data structure. The only way to create it from JNI is by using regular Java class, which will be far more difficult from JNI than from Java. And I don't see what you can gain by using JNI at all.

Comment: JNI call is much faster and create less memory issue i have tested the above code. but the code in java ie, to decodeBytearray to bitmap  takes long time and memory. ANd also i  am decoding large bitmap here without scaling.

Comment: I don't know why you would do any of this in JNI. You should be using `ImageIO` for this. Certainly what you've written so far will have zero benefit from being written in JNI, and it contains at least one bug already.

Comment: `buffer[length+1] = '\0';`?  A bitmap of binary data is not a NUL-terminated string.  And `fopen (path,"r");`?  That's text mode.  And you're not checking the return value from `fread()` so you have no idea if you actually read data from the file.  And the results will certainly be interesting if the `fopen()` call fails.